# Drawable half-half colors / Only xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

Is it possible to create a drawable (I guess a layer-list) splitted by two:

Half color (half left) be e.g. red, other right be green. But **not use fixed** `dp` **values**.

Think of like we can do with [android-weigth for Linear and Relative layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036929/how-to-arrange-width-and-height-of-relative-layout-to-be-half-of-the-screen/), but a drawable.

Is something like that possible **only with XML code?**

Comment: yes, layer-list tag with one shape and a clip with another shape

Comment: @pskink could you write an example? I tried unsuccessfully with layer-list and scale drawables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#0f0" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#f00" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

make sure to call view.getBackground().setLevel(5000) in order to see half red half green output